# Is 0 positive in assembly?

Tags: assembly

As question title states.

Is 0 positive in assembly language when carrying out a branch if positive operation?

Comment: Which Assembly language? Couldn't you write a simple branch and test it to verify this yourself?

Comment: @Hunter I don't know a great deal about assembly tbh but I thought it'd be safe to assume something like this would have the same result in all languages?

Comment: Zero **is** non-negative and non-positive, assembly has nothing to do with it. For particular design of CPU and reasoning about what happens when zero is used by some instruction in particular context please specify the CPU and context. Assembly is not programming language like others, it's more like textual representation of HW design of CPU chip, so every CPU can have different instructions and quirks (including treating zero value as negative, although I never heard about such HW design yet, but if somebody would want to make it... they can)

Comment: That depends on your architecture.  Generally, no, it is not.

Comment: *"branch if positive"* - then it shouldn't be taken, unless it is some documented quirk, when zero is treated as positive. The possible designs of branching and value testing are broadly different over CPUs, so it's impossible to answer in some general way, but HW guys are usually very reasonable and math-based, so if the instruction says "branch when positive", it shouldn't accept zero, that would have more likely wording "branch when non-negative" or something similar.

Comment: Alright  thanks, if you put that in an answer I'll accept if for you.

Comment: for x86: if a calculation like `add` result in 0, the zero- and parity-flag will be set, the carry- and overflow-flag may be set and the sign- and auxiliary-flag will be cleared. assuming the result is really zero (no borrow, carry nor overflow), then the carry- and overflow-flags are cleared too. in any case, a `jns` will always jump, if the result is zero just like it is a positve value, so yes: zero is positive.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Depends on the specific language, but generally Zero is not 'truthy'.

Comment: what does truthy mean?

Comment: A slang term for 'A value considered True when used as a condition'.

Comment: @andrew: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey explains the terminology, and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89342/is-it-truthy-or-falsy is an exploration.  I think code-golf uses those terms because choosing convenient values for true and false (other than something standard like `bool`) often enables smaller code.  In real life you don't normally optimize that heavily.

Comment: This is answering a different question than asked.  Also, a zero result typically sets ZF on architectures that have flags at all, but there are usually choices of branches that let you branch if ZF is set, or branch if ZF is clear, so you have your choice of whether 0 or non-zero is truthy.  In assembly language, you often want to deal with an inverted condition where zero means "true" for some temporary result.